# How To Get Alert Box To Display All Dropdown Selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new at JavaScript and I'm using Chosen to make this. I want to have all the fields that get selected in the dropdown boxes to display in my ending alert box (Click Me Box).

How can I go about doing this?

Here is a link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nikole/Xp338/37/

Here's the HTML portion of my code:

```
  <script>
  function outCome()
  {
  alert('Hello! I am an alert box!');
  }
  </script>
  <div id="Task" name="tBox"></div>
 <br/><br/>
  <div id="Urgency" name="uBox"></div>
  <div id="Time"></div>
  <div id="Who"></div>
  <div id="When" name="whenBox"></div>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="outCome()">Let's do it! Click to send</button>
```

Do I really need the name tags?
Thanks so much to those that help me. As I said I am a newbie and really want to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `jquery version` **1.9 or higher** and try this,

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var arr=[];
    $('select').each(function(){
      arr.push(this.value);
    });
    alert('Seleced='+arr.join(', '));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vXebc/)

Comment: This was awesome!! Thanks so much for helping a newbie. I will use this version because you showed me how to add the feature where I can say to the user what their outcome is (Selected or You selected). Thanks so much, I am very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

$("#dropdownid option:selected").text();

Comment: This one didn't work for me. But thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle example, it seems that you are using both Javascript and Jquery.
You can get this both with javascript or Jquery but in my personal opinion Jquery will be much simpler

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var TaskValue = $('#Task').find('.chosen-single').text()
    var UrgencyValue = $('#Urgency').find('.chosen-single').text()
    var TimeValue = $('#Time').find('.chosen-single').text()
    var WhoValue = $('#Who').find('.chosen-single').text()
    var WhenValue = $('#When').find('.chosen-single').text()
    alert(TaskValue +"\n"+ UrgencyValue +"\n"+ TimeValue +"\n"+ WhoValue +"\n"+ WhenValue)
})
```

In this method you can choose which value to show first and whats the next value.

Comment: This is a great option! I didn't realize before that I was using two different versions. It works very well. Thank you.